# Sprintf function + order arguments

Tags: c, string, printf

I have two string ta and tb with certain value, then I use the function sprintf to concatenate the two both in the variable ta, when I write

```
sprintf(ta,"%s+%s",ta,tb);
```

I get the string `1+2`. but I need store in ta the string `2+1` then I trying

```
sprintf(ta,"%s+%s",tb,ta);
```

but I get the string `2+2+2+2+`. I don't understand why happens that, Could you help me please?. Below the complete code

```
int main() {
    char ta[5];
    char tb[5];
    sprintf(ta,"%d",1);
    sprintf(tb,"%d",2);
    sprintf(ta,"%s+%s",ta,tb);
    //sprintf(ta,"%s+%s",tb,ta); uncomment for the second case
    printf("taid:%s",ta);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sprintf(ta,"%s+%s",ta,tb);
sprintf(ta,"%s+%s",tb,ta);
```

Both lines of calling `sprintf` have undefined behavior. You are trying to copy `ta` to `ta` itself.

> #### C11 §7.21.6.6 The `sprintf` function
>
> The `sprintf` function is equivalent to `fprintf`, except that the output is written into an array (specified by the argument `s`) rather than to a stream. A null character is written at the end of the characters written; it is not counted as part of the returned value. **If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.**